# How to handle null values as 0 with sum()?

Tags: xquery

In XQuery, I want to sum values that are not null (effectively count null as 0). I've tried the following without success.

```
sum(data(//Line/Total))
```

I get this error

> Cannot cast untypedAtomic: to double

How can I do this in one step?

```
sum(data(//Line[Total !='']/Total))
```

Sample XML:

```
<Order>
    <Line>
          <Total>1</Total>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <Total>1</Total>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <Total></Total>
    </Line>
</Order>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a predicate to ensure that only the values that can be evaluated as a `number()` are included in the `sum()`. Ensure that the `number()` value is equal to it's `number()` value, since `NaN` will not equal `NaN`.

```
sum(/Order/Line/Total[number() = number()])
```

Or ensure that the value is castable as `xs:double`

```
sum(/Order/Line/Total[. castable as xs:double])
```

Comment: The first proposal is incorrect. Be aware that `number()` will return a numeric value if it can be parsed -- and when predicated contain numbers, they will be shorthand for positional predicates, so your first query merely means `sum(/Order/Line/Total[position() = number()])`. I like your third proposal, though.

Comment: @JensErat - good point. Thanks for spotting that. Quick validation with sample data had worked, but just happened to produce the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

An empty value (if not defined more specifically through XML schema) has no specific type attached and thus the very general type `untypedAtomic`. From this,  no type can be derived -- that's why you get the error message it cannot be casted.

You have to exclude those empty values somehow. @Mads Hansen proposed filtering for those elements that can be casted as `xs:double`, which is a very elegant solution, which I would go for. To just remove *empty* values, you could also test for elements not having any data stored:

```
sum(/Order/Line/Total[data()])
```

but be aware of elements containing strings that cannot be parsed as numbers, whitespace not removed, ...

Comment: To filter out empty *and* whitespace-only items, you could use `sum(/Order/Line/Total[normalize-space(.)])`

Comment: The context item is always a single item, so empty(.) is always false.

Comment: Indeed. That was too late at night. Changed the answer to something more reasonable, actually looking _into_ the element.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case where using the text nodes rather than the elements is convenient: `sum(/Order/Line/Total/text())`.